# Как сделать анимацию движения картинки с ускорением при отпускании?

Tags: c#, математика

Нужно сделать плавное движение за курсором с задержкой (что бы "плыл за ним"). Если кнопка отпускается, то картинка продолжает передвигаться с ускорением до определенной координаты, после чего его начинает отталкивать обратно уменьшив ускорение, а затем увеличить ее до прежних значений переместив картинку обратно на позицию старта.

```
if (!MultiSleeper<string>.Sleeping("QueenUltUPD"))
{
   SleeperYPos = QueenUltRect.Y * 100;
   MultiSleeper<string>.Sleep("QueenUltUPD", 100);
}
AvrSpeed = SleeperYPos / MathF.Ceiling((GameManager.GameTime - (TimeStart)) * 1000);
```

Попытался сделать что-то свое, но выглядит топорно и резкими перемещениями, хотелось сделать бы плавнее.

[image: Примерная визуализация]

Comment: это не так важно, но думаю лучше было бы прикрепить гифку того, как сейчас выглядит анимация, если есть такая возможность; а, ну и указать что за тип приложения, wpf winforms или что это?

Comment: @Pekor просто картинка быстро смещается на координаты вниз вот и все. Курсор вниз тяну и отпускаю и она просто перемещается